# regex to add \n after certain number of characters and space

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that can add \n after a certain number of characters and if last character is word, it should push that word to next line.

I have below regex that does the job of adding \n but instead of pushing last word to next line it keeps the word in that line.

```
word.replace(/(.{12}) /g, "$&\n")
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me or tell me if it is possible or not to do so.

example:

```
word = "love stackoverflow"
after regex it should be love \n stackoverflow 
NOT love stackoverflow\n
```

Comment: What is condition? Empty space should be replaced with \n, or? You said 'after certian number of characters' - does it mean that string longer than X (12 in your regex) chars should be placed in two lines?

Comment: if my string is longer than 12 characters, than add \n after 12 characters. but if it is a word, than don't break the word, instead got to space before that word and add \n . 
So \n should be added only after empty space, and not in between the word.

Comment: my current script add \n to space but after the word, not to the space before the word.

Comment: Why are you doing this? If you are trying to break words for output in the browser, you should consider using various CSS properties, although they will break based on width rather than character count.

Comment: I think you are better off writing a little program to do this, instead of trying to use regexp.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but it might give some ideas:

```
.{1,12}(?=[\W])
```

Looks for as many characters as it can find (between 1 and 12) until it finds a character followed by a non-letter (such as a space, line terminator, punctuation, etc..).

https://regex101.com/r/UceAEC/1

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can implement it in python. Port this logic to JavaScript.
I have taken a more meaningful length of 12 characters. You can substitute 8 if you like in the regex.

```
import re

a = "The a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
print [b+'\n' for b in re.findall("(.{0,12})(?: |$)",a) if b]
```

Output:

```
['The a quick\n', 'brown fox\n', 'jumps over\n', 'the lazy dog\n']
```

Demo on Regex101 for your string that you have mentioned:
https://regex101.com/r/lmdjwT/1